# Unexpected invalid cast

Tags: f#

the following F# code doesn't compile

```
open Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR

type Hub1() = 
    inherit Hub()

let ctx1 = Unchecked.defaultof<IHubContext<Hub1>>

let ctx2: IHubContext = upcast ctx1
let ctx3 = ctx1 :> IHubContext
```

However, according to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/hubcontext?view=aspnetcore-7.0#use-ihubcontext-in-generic-code), it should. What am I missing?

Comment: There are two kinds of downcasts in F#: static and dynamic. You have a static downcast, but I think you need a dynamic one, so try using `:?>` instead of `:>`.

Comment: @BrianBerns You are right, I had incorrectly assumed that the inheritance was the other way around.